# How can I indicate result ambiguity with Resharper CodeAnnotation attributes?

Tags: c#, resharper, code-contracts, resharper-8.0, resharper-7.1

Using Resharper's code-annotation attributes, I'm trying to write a ContractAnnotation attribute for a method that will always return null if the input is null, but will return *either* null or a value if the input is not null. Something like:

```cs
[ContractAnnotation("null => null; notnull => null||notnull")]
```

I would just write this on its own:

```cs
[ContractAnnotation("null => null")]
```

Except that according to [Contract Annotations in ReSharper 7](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/08/15/contract-annotations-in-resharper-7/), this would be automatically complemented with something that is invalid:

> `null => null` omits the parameter name in cases there is only one parameter. Basically, `null => null` means that if the parameter has the value `null`, the method return value is also `null`. Note also that this annotation is automatically complemented with `notnull => notnull`.

How might I write the `ContractAnnotation` attribute to indicate that it cannot be certain what the return value is when the input is `notnull`?

Or alternatively, how can I *stop* it from automatically complementing my `null => null` annotation with `notnull => notnull`

---

**Bonus question:**

How could I write something like the following:

```cs
[ContractAnnotation("null => true; notnull => true||false")]
```

Or in that case, would this be sufficient, since it is not automatically complemented with the inverse?

```cs
[ContractAnnotation("null => true")]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `canbenull`:

```
[ContractAnnotation("null => null; notnull => canbenull")]
```

The full grammar is:

```
FDT      ::= FDTRow [;FDTRow]*
FDTRow   ::= Input => Output | Output <= Input
Input    ::= ParameterName: Value [, Input]*
Output   ::= [ParameterName: Value]* {halt|stop|void|nothing|Value}
Value    ::= true | false | null | notnull | canbenull
```

As for the bonus question, `[ContractAnnotation("null => true")]` should be sufficient. Saying that a `bool`-returning function can return `true` or `false` is redundant, as it can't possibly return anything else.

Comment: Thank you! I completely missed the `canbenull` value when I was reading the documentation. What's your opinion on the bonus question I added above?

Comment: @Ben I added the answer to the bonus question

Comment: Yes, you're right, it would be redundant, I just wasn't sure if you had to be unambiguous about all possible execution paths.